# Does declaring methods like alert() override the built-in alert() method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was experimenting to define the built-in method `alert()` to see what kind of error the console will throw, but instead the built-in `alert()` got overridden.

This is the code -

```
function alert(some_string) {
    console.log(some_string+some_string);
}

function say() {
    alert("Hello");
}

say();
```

The output is : **HelloHello**

Coming from a Java background, it would throw a compile error as :

> **error: method alert() is already defined**

So what happened here? Did I actually override the method?

Comment: Overriding functions isn't a big deal in JavaScript. But understandably not always a good idea...

Comment: There might be hundreds of built-in functions and I might accidentally define a function with a same name as one of them, how can I check if such accidents don't happen?

Comment: The point is that in JS such definition actually means (re)defining a property of the global object (`window`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overriding is a classical OO term which means that a child class has method with the same name as one of the classes it inherits from which is used instead of that method on the child class.

In this case, you are straight up taking the `alert` variable (which by default has a value of a function provided by the browser) and assigning it a new value (the function you just declared).

(That assumes you are working in the global scope. If you were in a local scope you would just be masking the variable so you would only be making `alert` inaccessible to other code in the same scope … and since you were writing that code too, it wouldn't be a problem because you would know if you needed the global `alert` and could avoid reusing its name.)

> There might be hundreds of built-in functions and I might accidentally define a function with a same name as one of them, how can I check if such accidents don't happen?

There are two basic techniques for this.

**Avoid creating globals**

When you create a new variable, do it in as narrow a scope as possible. A common pattern is to use an IIFE to create a new scope for all the variables related to a given piece of code.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    function alert() {
        // Locally scoped alert that doesn't get in the way
        // of any variable called `alert` from the browser
        // or another library
    }

})();
```

**Use namespaces**

This is just a term for having a single global as the entry point to a bunch of related code. It is usually given an ALL_CAPS name that is unlikely to conflict with other code.

This allows the functions to be accessed from anywhere, like globals, without creating lots of global variables.

```
var MYLIBRARY;

(function () {
    "use strict";

    MYLIBRARY = {
        alert: alert
    };

    function alert() { /* etc */ }

})();
```